# Grails - Passing selected checkboxes

Tags: grails, checkbox

I've done a Javascript method that grabs all the selected checkboxes within a declared name and performs a method.

Out of curiousity, how would one do something with JUST Grails?

For example:

```
 <g:checkBox name="personList" value="${person.id}"/>

 <g:form params="[people:personList]">
      <g:actionSubmit action="x" controller="bank" value="Pass These IDss"/>
 </g:form>
```

The params for the form would theoretically include the list of all selected check boxes in the personList checkBox group. (what I did I assume isn't correct).

Comment: See [Grails checkbox handling](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8196321/462015)

Comment: Thanks Arturo. I'll take a look at Commands. I tried an initial run through using the session to pass the list, but that gave me nothing. So I am not sure how that worked in the accepted answer.

Comment: No luck. I would think this is straight forward with Grails. I have pre-existing JQuery calls to methods on button calls. But I need to render the page after the calls. So catch-22..

Answer (score 0):

You simply have to include your `<g:checkbox />` tags into the `<g:form> </g:form>` tags I think. 
Then in the *bank* controller, in the *x* action, the data will be available at `params.personList`.

Comment: This is what I tried unfortunately. The value of the personList is nothing. No matter which check boxes are selected.